# akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException is thrown while persisting an event

Tags: java, cassandra, akka, lagom

I just started with Lagom & Akka. I am following the design decribed in ***[Domain Modelling with Akka Persistence Typed](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/java/UsingAkkaPersistenceTyped.html)***

I am trying to create a brand new instance of an entity (`EntityState`). But the  event is not getting persisted, and I am getting the following error:

```
00:54:27.862 [error] com.example.impl.entity.EntityClass [persistencePhase=running-cmd, akkaAddress=akka://XXX@127.0.0.1:60685, akkaSource=akka://XXX/system/sharding/StateClass/186/ID1, sourceActorSystem=XXX, persistenceId=StateClass|ID1] - Supervisor StopSupervisor saw failure: null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at akka.persistence.typed.javadsl.EventSourcedBehavior.$anonfun$apply$4(EventSourcedBehavior.scala:195)
    at akka.persistence.typed.internal.Running$RunningState.applyEvent(Running.scala:78)
    at akka.persistence.typed.internal.Running$HandlingCommands.applyEffects(Running.scala:153)
    at akka.persistence.typed.internal.Running$HandlingCommands.onCommand(Running.scala:123)
    at akka.persistence.typed.internal.Running$HandlingCommands.onMessage(Running.scala:105)
    at akka.persistence.typed.internal.Running$HandlingCommands.onMessage(Running.scala:100)
    at akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.AbstractBehavior.receive(AbstractBehavior.scala:83)
```

I have a **Create** command, which invokes `onCreate()`, and eventually attempts to persist an **EntityCreated** event.

**Service Impl method**

```
@Override
public ServiceCall<CreateMessage, StateView> createState(){
    return message ->
            entityRef(message.getName())
                    .<EntityClass.Accepted>ask(replyTo -> new EntityClass.Create(message, replyTo), askTimeout)
                    .thenApply(accepted -> toStateView(accepted.getSummary()));
}
```

**Command handler:**

```
private ReplyEffect<Event, StateClass> onCreate(StateClass state, Create cmd) {
    return Effect()
            .persist(new EntityCreated(cmd.getDetails().getName(), Instant.now()))
            .thenReply(cmd.replyTo, e -> new Accepted(EntityClass.toSummary(e)));
}
```

I am able to confirm the following:

- exception is thrown during `persist()`
- the event is not present in Cassandra

Your help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Guided by the auto-generated HelloWorld example, placing the event in a different package than the service implementation class resulted in this error. Th moment I move **HelloWorldEvent** to a package as `com.example.helloworld.impl.aggregate.event`, I start getting the exception. When I place it back inside `com.example.helloworld.impl`, which is the same package where **HelloWorldServiceImpl**, the exception is resolved.
Even changing access modifiers to public did not help... Does anyone have an explanation?
I was hoping that I would be able to organize classes into packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the real cause for the exception was because I should have added logic for handling the event as follows:
in `helloEvents()`, I needed to add logic similar to the following:

```
if (eventAndOffset.first() instanceof HelloEvent.GreetingMessageChanged) {
    HelloEvent.GreetingMessageChanged messageChanged = (HelloEvent.GreetingMessageChanged) eventAndOffset.first();
    eventToPublish = new GreetingMessageChanged(messageChanged.getName(), messageChanged.getMessage());
}
```

In Addition, in the aggregate's `eventHandler()`, I needed to add logic similar to the following:

```
builder.forAnyState()
    .onEvent(GreetingMessageChanged.class, (state, evt) ->
        // We simply update the current state to use the greeting message from
        // the event.
        state.withMessage(evt.message)
);
```